# Cannot assign to property: <Enum:case> is not settable

Tags: swift, enums

for example we have simple enum

```
public enum CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem {
    case cancel
    case done
    case now

    private static var titles: [CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem: String] = [
        .cancel: "Cancel",
        .done: "Done",
        .now: "Now",
    ]

    public var title: String  {
        get { return CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[self] ?? String(describing: self) }
        // what am I want to do
        set(value) { CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[self] = value }
    }

    // what am I forced to do
    public static func setTitle(_ title: String, for item: CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem) {
        CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[item] = title
    }
}
```

why I don't can set new title like this

```
CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel.title = "asd"
```

compiler responded error - **Cannot assign to property: 'cancel' is not settable**, but I can set title with function

```
CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.setTitle("asd", for: .cancel)
```

what should I change for worked my var as settable? `.cancel.title = "asd"`

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to change the underlying `enum`'s values rather than an instance of the `enum`… I mean apart from the global effect this will have on all instance of the enum?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using an enum for this seems inappropriate, but I'll address the porblem at face value. You need to mark your setter as `nonmutating`, so that it can be called on non-`var` instances of your enum:

```
public enum CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem {

    // ...

    public var title: String  {
        get { return CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[self] ?? String(describing: self) }
        nonmutating set(value) { CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[self] = value }
    }
}

CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel.title = "foo" // Works... but why would you want this?!
```

Comment: thanks! all this for example, but I want use it for localizable buttons in pod from project

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason why you can't do that is because the Swift compiler sees enum cases as immutable by default (similar to an immutable `struct` declared with `let`), and here you are trying to mutate it.

A good way to see this is if you try to add a mutating function to this enum

```
mutating public func setTitle2(_ newValue: String) {
    CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.titles[self] = newValue
}
```

You will then receive the error message

```
error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'cancel' returns immutable value
```

#### How to work around this

One way to have a similar behavior is by changing this enum into a set of static variables (which is more consistent with what you are trying to achieve).

```
public struct CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem {

    var title: String

    static var cancel = CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel")
    static var done = CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem(title: "Done")
    static var now = CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem(title: "Now")

}
```

Now you can use the following

```
CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel.title = "asd"
```

Also, you still have the ability to use the dot-syntax

```
let buttonItem: CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem = .cancel // it works
```

Hope that helps!

---

**TD;DR:** Because `enum` is an immutable object.

Comment: but I don't mutating enum, my var inside enum compiled - ok, and inner var method same on as func, and func for fine, they mutating only static var

Comment: Yes but from the Swift compiler's perspective, there is no difference if your variable is computed or stored, you always need to be allowed to mutate the object if you want to use a setter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Whatever you're trying to do here – it's certainly not a good approach and pretty dangerous. As Craig pointed out in his comment, you're messing around with instance properties and static properties. You can have multiple instances of an enum – but when you want to change the title of a particular instance, you also change the title for all other instances. That's unexpected behavior and you should really think of another solution.

---

That being said, your code actually *does* work – with a little modification: Instead of

```
CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel.title = "asd"
```

you can write

```
var item = CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel
item.title = "asd"
```

This will compile.

---

The reason behind it is that an enum is a *value type*. Everytime you create an instance of an enum type, e.g. `var item = CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel`, the enum's value is copied into the new variable `item`. You can choose if you want that value to be mutable or not by using either `var` or `let`. That's how Swift enums are intended to be used.

A single enum case like `CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel` is immutable by definition.

```
CXActionSheetToolBarButtonItem.cancel.title = "asd"
```

wouldn't have any meaning because **there is no instance to which the title can be assigned**. The enum case `.cancel` is not bound to a variable.